# How to Setup Proxy Pass and Location blocks in an Nginx Ingress object for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to figure out the best to setup Proxy Pass and Location blocks in an Ingress Nginx object for Kubernetes.

I would like to convert the below Nginx location blocks in Ingress Nginx:

```
location ^~ /_health {
    types { } default_type "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    return 200 "UP";
}

location  /fineract-provider/ {
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
  access_log off;

  client_max_body_size 100M;

  proxy_pass "https://localhost:8443";
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

This is the best I've come up with, but it's not complete yet:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: ""
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: my-web-app.com
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
    - host: my-web-app.com
      paths:
      - path: /_health
        pathType: Prefix
    - host: my-web-app.com
      paths:
      - path: /fineract-provider/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fineract-api
            port:
              number: 8443
```

Will appreciate any form of help.